# Create link to specific jQuery tab

Tags: html, jquery, hyperlink, tabs

I've looked around and tried several things from similar post about jQuery tabs, but I can't get my code to work the same. Below is what I'm working with. Goal is to have the link open the correct tab.

Link to the tab:

```
 <li><a onClick="$('.tabs').selectorr('.about', 250).click()" href="#">About Us</a></li>
```

The code for my tabs:

```
<ul class="tabs">
            <li>
                <h3>Games</h3>
                <div class="split">
                        <p>Current Games</p>
                        <div>Tab 1 content</div>                        
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3 class="about">Who We Are</h3>
                <div class="split reversed">
                        <div>Tab 2 content</div>
                </div>
            </li>
</ul>
```

My main.js to call the tab: this is called when the page initially loads, which selects the first h3

```
    $('.tabs').selectorr({
        titleSelector: 'h3',
        delay: 250
    });
```

The selectorr function:

```
/* jquery.selectorr v0.2 | (c) @ajlkn | MIT licensed */
!function(e){
    e.fn.selectorr=function(t){
        var i=e(this),s=e.extend({
            titleSelector:".title",delay:0
        },t);
        if(0==this.length)
            return i;
        if(this.length>1){
            for(var a=0;a<this.length;a++)e.selectorr(e(this[a]),s);
            return i
        }
        return e.selectorr(i,s)
    },e.selectorr=function(t,i){
        var s,a,l,n=t.children("li"),r=e('<div><ul class="titles"></ul><div class="panels"></div></div>').insertAfter(t),c=r.find(".titles"),d=r.find(".panels"),o=0,v=!1;(l=n.filter(".active")).length>0&&(o=l.index()),n.each(function(t){
            var l,n,r,f,u=e(this);
            r=u.find(i.titleSelector),f=r.attr("href"),l=e('<li class="title">'+r.html()+"</li>"),c.append(l),r.remove(),l.css("cursor","pointer"),u.wrapInner('<div class="panel" />'),n=u.children("div"),n.appendTo(d),l.on("click",function(e){
                if(v||l.hasClass("active"))return!1;
                if(f)return location.href=f,!1;v=!0,s.removeClass("active"),l.addClass("active");
                var t=a.filter(".active");
                return t.length>0?(t.removeClass("active"),setTimeout(function(){
                    t.css("display","none"),n.show(),n.addClass("active"),setTimeout(function(){
                        v=!1},i.delay)
                },i.delay)):(n.css("display",""),n.addClass("active"),setTimeout(function(){
                    v=!1
                },i.delay)),!1
            }),t==o?(l.addClass("active"),n.addClass("active")):n.css("display","none")
        }),r.attr("id",t.attr("id")).attr("class",t.attr("class")),t.remove(),s=c.find(".title"),a=d.find(".panel")
    }
}(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plugin replace previous html and add new htmls i.e : `<li class="title">..</li>` so `.about` doesn't exist in your `dom` . Instead you can use `'$(".titles li:eq(1)").trigger("click")'` to trigger second `li` i.e : about tab .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
/* jquery.selectorr v0.2 | (c) @ajlkn | MIT licensed */ ! function(e) {
  e.fn.selectorr = function(t) {
    var i = e(this),
      s = e.extend({
        titleSelector: ".title",
        delay: 0
      }, t);
    if (0 == this.length)
      return i;
    if (this.length > 1) {
      for (var a = 0; a < this.length; a++) e.selectorr(e(this[a]), s);
      return i
    }
    return e.selectorr(i, s)
  }, e.selectorr = function(t, i) {
    var s, a, l, n = t.children("li"),
      r = e('<div><ul class="titles"></ul><div class="panels"></div></div>').insertAfter(t),
      c = r.find(".titles"),
      d = r.find(".panels"),
      o = 0,
      v = !1;
    (l = n.filter(".active")).length > 0 && (o = l.index()), n.each(function(t) {
      var l, n, r, f, u = e(this);
      r = u.find(i.titleSelector), f = r.attr("href"), l = e('<li class="title">' + r.html() + "</li>"), c.append(l), r.remove(), l.css("cursor", "pointer"), u.wrapInner('<div class="panel" />'), n = u.children("div"), n.appendTo(d), l.on("click", function(e) {
        if (v || l.hasClass("active")) return !1;
        if (f) return location.href = f, !1;
        v = !0, s.removeClass("active"), l.addClass("active");
        var t = a.filter(".active");
        return t.length > 0 ? (t.removeClass("active"), setTimeout(function() {
          t.css("display", "none"), n.show(), n.addClass("active"), setTimeout(function() {
            v = !1
          }, i.delay)
        }, i.delay)) : (n.css("display", ""), n.addClass("active"), setTimeout(function() {
          v = !1
        }, i.delay)), !1
      }), t == o ? (l.addClass("active"), n.addClass("active")) : n.css("display", "none")
    }), r.attr("id", t.attr("id")).attr("class", t.attr("class")), t.remove(), s = c.find(".title"), a = d.find(".panel")
  }
}(jQuery);


$('.tabs').selectorr({
  titleSelector: 'h3',
  delay: 250
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li>
    <h3>Games</h3>
    <div class="split">
      <p>Current Games</p>
      <div>Tab 1 content</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 class="about">Who We Are</h3>
    <div class="split reversed">
      <div>Tab 2 content</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<!--click on second li-->
<a onclick='$(".titles li:eq(1)").trigger("click")' href="#">About Us</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is my home.php file. So if I were on a different page but wanted to link to the home.php "about us" section how would I go about passing that information? Is it something that can be passed in the URL..? I'm using CodeIgniter framework so maybe it can be passed through the controller or URI segment?

Comment: Hi, if you know `li` which you need to display you can pass index no of `li` like if want to open first `li` pass `0` for second pass `1` and so on . Then you just need to use that value here `$(".titles li:eq("+valuewhichpass+")")`

Comment: So then I'd use an if else statement to determine if I'm on the home.php page, if not then redirect to the home.php with the URI segment "valuewhichpass". Then in the Home Controller I can check to see if a URI segment exists...if it does then pass the value to the Li, if not pass the value 0.

Comment: yes something like that see if that works or not